# data-menuanchor in FullPage.js is not working properly in Jekyll templates

Tags: html, css, jekyll, fullpage.js

Consider this code:

site__header.html

```
<ul id="anchor__links" class="anchor__links">
  <li data-menuanchor="section1" class="active"><a href="#section1">Intro</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="section2"><a href="#section2">What I Love</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="section3"><a href="#section3">What I Do</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="section4"><a href="#section4">My Works</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="section5"><a href="#section5">My Blog</a></li>
  <li data-menuanchor="section6"><a href="#section6">Get In Touch</a></li>
</ul>
```

home.html

```
---
layout: page
class: home
permalink: /
title: Home
navigation_match: /
---

<article id="fullpage">
    <div class="section article__section" id="sec__1">
    </div>
    <div class="section article__section" id="sec__2">
    </div>
    <div class="section article__section" id="sec__3">
    </div>
    <div class="section article__section" id="sec__4">
    </div>
    <div class="section article__section" id="sec__5">
    </div>
    <div class="section article__section" id="sec__6">
    </div>
</article>
```

main.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Enable FullpageJS
  jQuery('#fullpage').fullpage({
    scrollBar: false,
    keyboardScrolling: true,
    fitToSection: true,
    css3: true,
    scrollingSpeed: 800,
    fixedElements: '#header, .slide__indicator',
    anchors: ['section1', 'section2', 'section3', 'section4', 'section5', 'section6'],
    menu: '#anchor__links'
  });
});
```

Here is a recorded demo of my problem. 
**https://www.screencast.com/t/nFKRtFC9Ep**

The problem I have is that the menu is not working properly when I tried to click on the menu items at the top of the page. As I clicked the button, nothing happens like page section transitions (e.g. transition from section 1 to section 2), however, when I scroll down the rest of the pages, the active menu item transitions from one item to the other as it should be. Regarding with the sections having their own IDs, I don't want to remove them because I have specific styles for each of them.

Comment: So just moments ago, I resolved this issue by just arranging the position of my main js (I only have 1 main js file will all the vendor js and my custom scripts concatenated to one another) on top of the `<head>` of my default.html. I guess problem solved from here.